# I need to find average price for two products in two separate tables where maker is the same for both

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate

**The problem:** Find out the average price of PCs and laptops produced by maker A.
Result set: one overall average price for all items.

Product table:

[image]

PC table:

[image]

Printer table:

[image]

Laptop table:

[image]

**My code:**

```
select (avg(pc.price)+avg(printer.price))/2 from pc, printer
where pc.model IN
(SELECT product.model from PRODUCT where maker='A')
AND
printer.model IN
(SELECT printer.model from product where maker  = 'A')
```

**My result and the correct result:**  [image]

Comment: SELECT printer.model from product where maker  = 'A' ???? seems wrong to me...  .. and in your data sample there is not printer model that match  .. you data sample is not coherent ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the requirement is the average of 2 averages.
What you can do is select all prices of pcs and all prices of laptops by maker 'A' and find the average of all.
You will have to use `UNION ALL` to select all the prices from both tables `pc` and `laptop`:

```
select avg(t.price) AVG_price from (
  select price from pc
  where model in (select model from product where maker = 'A')
  union all
  select price from laptop
  where model in (select model from product where maker = 'A')
) t
```

But if it is the case of the average of averages, then by following the same logic, calculate the 2 averages and apply `UNION ALL` to get the average of them:

```
select avg(t.price) AVG_price from (
  select avg(price) price from pc
  where model in (select model from product where maker = 'A')
  union all
  select avg(price) price from laptop
  where model in (select model from product where maker = 'A')
) t
```

Comment: @forpes It doesn't allow me to write code like yours, it says there's a syntax error around ')' I tried do move the parenthesis of the subquery elsewhere, it didn't work and tried also to remove the parenthesis altogether, then it showed that there is an error around select, I assume that the program doesn't like that right after FROM there is a select statement. The site runs SQL server.

Comment: Copy the queries now.

Comment: @forpes Thank you, now it's correct, how to tell when some subquery needs an alias in a situation like this?

Comment: The problem was not the alias as I thought initially, I did not  include `from product` in the inner subqueries. As for the aliases there are databases like MySQL where all subqueries must have an alias, so when you write `select * from ( ... )` is wrong but `select * from ( ... ) t` is correct.